# Leaflet choropleth maps in shiny - unable to use addPolygons function properly

Tags: r, maps, shiny, leaflet, choropleth

I am new to writing shiny apps and new to using the leaflet package. I am trying to create a shiny app which will get user inputs and plot a choropleth map based on the aggregated values of the selected user variable.

My sample dataset has the following variables: statename    latitude    longitude   countyname  medianage   asianpopulation otherpopulation

My app would ask the user to select from either username or countyname. Based on this selection, internally I group my dataset using statename or countyname.

Then the user selects either one or many from the variables: medianage  asianpopulation otherpopulation.

Based on this, I want to plot the choropleth map on the sum of the values of these variables and show a table below with these values.

I am not able to use the addPolygons method to plot the map. Do I need to use a shape file for this? Where am I going wrong in this code?

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(leaflet)
library(lazyeval)
library(rgdal)

setwd("E:/Data")


ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Filters"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("level", "Select the Level", choices = c("State", "County"),selected = "State" ,inline = TRUE),
        selectInput("variable", "Variable Name", choices = NULL, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, selected = "medianage")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        leafletOutput("map"),
        dataTableOutput("heatmapdata")
      )
    )

  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  read_csv(file="Sample.csv") %>% 
          select(statename, latitude, longitude, countyname, medianage, asianpopulation, otherpopulation) -> heatmapData -> hd

  variable = c()
  group = c()

  heatmapData <- data.frame(heatmapData)
  hd <- heatmapData

  heatmapdata_1 <- select(heatmapData, -c(latitude, longitude))
  heatmapdata_2 <- select(heatmapdata_1, -c(statename, countyname))

  updateSelectInput(session, "variable", choices = sort(unique(colnames(heatmapData))), selected = "medianage")

  heatmapdata_2 <- heatmapdata_1

  datasetLevel.group <- function(df, grp.var) {
    df %>% group_by_(grp.var) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(sum)) -> df

    df
  }

  datasetLevel <- reactive({
    heatmapdata_2 <- heatmapdata_1
    inputvariable <- c("medianage")

    if (input$level == "State") {
      inputlevel = c("statename")
      heatmapdata_2 <- select(heatmapdata_2, -c(countyname))
    }

    if (input$level == "County") {
      inputlevel = c("countyname")
      heatmapdata_2 <- select(heatmapdata_2, -c(statename))
    }

    sm <- datasetLevel.group(heatmapdata_2, inputlevel)

    group <- inputlevel
    variable <- inputvariable

    l_hd <- list(sm, inputlevel, input$variable)
    l_hd

  }) 

  output$map <- renderLeaflet(
    {
      leaflet() %>% addTiles(options=tileOptions(minZoom = 3, maxZoom = 10)) %>%
        setView(lng = -98.35, lat = 39.5, zoom = 4) %>% 
        setMaxBounds( -180, 5, -52,  73) 
    }
  )

  output$heatmapdata <- renderDataTable(
        select_(datasetLevel()[[1]], datasetLevel()[[2]], datasetLevel()[[3]]),
      options = list(pageLength=5,
                     scrollX=TRUE,
                     lengthMenu = c(5, 10, 25, 100),
                     searching=FALSE)
  )

  observe({
    pal <- colorQuantile("YlOrRd", NULL, n = 20)
    leafletProxy("map", data = datasetLevel()[[1]]) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearMarkerClusters() #%>%
#       addPolygons(data = datasetLevel()[[1]],
#                   fillColor = ~pal(variable), 
#                   fillOpacity = 0.8, 
#                   color = "#BDBDC3", 
#                   weight = 1)
  })



 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have commented out the addPolygons code as I get an error with that. I have been breaking my head to get the maps color coded based on the aggregated values of the selected variable.

The data file can be found at: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4PQcgewfQ3-MF9lNjU4clpUcUk/view?usp=sharing

Any help on this will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [the documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shapes.html) tells you you need "Objects of `SpatialPolygons`, `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, `Polygon`, and `Polygons` class (from the `sp` package)". I recommend trying to build a basic map first, outside of shiny, so you understand how it works.